# Application crashes while sending gps location into server using async class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, client-server

I want to send my gps location into server but it shows error in doinbackground method, on the logcat longitude,latitude and deviceid displayed and after that application crashed.
This class showing my async class.

```
  private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
                {
                        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                             GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                             String lat=Double.toString(gps.getLatitude());
                             String lon=Double.toString(gps.getLongitude());

                            String url="http://m4yank.com/inhouse/mhere/api/api.php?q=track&uid=" +MainActivity.getDeviceId(MainActivity.this)+"&lat=" + lat + "&longt=" + lon;
                            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("url");
                           Log.d("Latitude", ""+lat);
                           Log.d("Longitude", ""+lon);
                           Log.d("Device id", ""+MainActivity.getDeviceId(MainActivity.this));

                            try {

                                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lon)); 
                                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                //Log.d("Latitude", ""+lat);
                               // Log.d("Longitude", ""+lon);
                              } 
                             catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             } 
                             catch (IOException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }



                            return null;
                        }



                    }
```

Error showing in logcat:

```
  12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=url
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.example.gps.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:251)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.example.gps.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-03 21:22:37.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):
```

Comment: Please show the LogCat output in your question.

Comment: What is line 258 of `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @Dale Wilson I have added the log

Comment: line 258: httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Answer (score 0):

There should be an error message saying what or where an error occurred.
I assume you have all needed permissions set in the manifest...

Comment: i have checked all the permission everything right in manifest

Answer (score 0):

`line 258: httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

Then `httppost` is `null`, as you are getting a `NullPointerException` on this line. I do not see where `httppost` is defined, let alone initialized.

Comment: I have changed the code i havn't initialize the httppost now initialized and an other error shown in logcat

Comment: @Illusionist: You are setting the URL to be `"url"`, which is not a valid URL.